# .NET Maui HttpClient file upload - unexpected end of stream

Tags: c#, .net-core, maui

I've got a .NET MAUI app that I am working on. When I try to debug it on Android, I get an error `unexpected end of stream`. I am running in an Android emulator (API 34). Here is my upload code. Any idea why this error is happening?  Any idea how to fix the error?  I have tried to debug my API endpoint, but my code never makes it out of the device as my breakpoint is not hit in Azure. TIA

```
var url = CreateUrl(userPicManagement);
var httpC = new MyHttp();
var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
var inputData = new StreamContent(stream);
content.Add(inputData, "file");
var response = await httpC.PostAsync(url, content);
```

Here is the `HttpClient` that I use. I add a couple of headers. I use this `HttpClient` call with other methods and have not had a problem.

```
public class MyHttp : System.Net.Http.HttpClient {
    
    public MyHttp(string tok = null) {
        this.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(xxxx, yyyyy);
        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tok)) {
            var str = String.Format("Bearer {0}", tok);
            this.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", tok);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A Multipart is MIME (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140) ) Is the stream MIME?  Each mime section starts with two dashes on a new line, contains a header, and data.  End of Stream implies the MIME is not complete.  Is the file you adding binary or text?

Comment: @jdweng I'm sending a jpg image.

Comment: You may want to convert to a base64 string.  An email can also use MIME.  See following for tips on sending MIME : https://mailtrap.io/blog/embedding-images-in-html-email-have-the-rules-changed/

Comment: Try modifying  the add method : content.Add(inputData, "image/jpeg","file");  The file should be the file path name

Comment: @jdweng I tried modifying the content.add method.  I am now getting an error along the lines of  Sent 259 request content bytes, but Content-Length promised 1968936.'

Comment: @jdweng converting to a base64 seems to have solved the problem.